# How to cancel form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to cancel submission of form when a javascript global varible is set to 0 :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
form_valid = 1;

function verifMdps() { // called in the onblur of a text input
    if (!mdpEquals()) {
        $('#errmsg_oldmdp').text("<?php echo _getText('service.personne.tbr_title.mdp_diff'); ?>");
        setTimeout(function(){$('#oldmdp').focus();}, 10);
        form_valid = 0;
    } else
        $('#errmsg_oldmdp').text("");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#frm").on("submit", function() {

        $( "input[onblur]:visible:enabled" ).each(function(){
            $(this).blur();
            if (form_valid == 0)
                return false;
        });

        if ( mode == "ajout" )
            $('#mode_').val("ajout");
        else
            $('#mode_').val("modif");

    });
```

Even if I write `return false` then the form is still submitted ! So how to cancel the submission ?

Comment: You need to move the return false outside of the each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the default action.

```
$("#frm").on("submit", function(e) {

        $( "input[onblur]:visible:enabled" ).each(function(){
            $(this).blur();
            if (form_valid == 0)
                e.preventDefault();
        });

        if ( mode == "ajout" )
            $('#mode_').val("ajout");
        else
            $('#mode_').val("modif");

    });
```