# how to cancel form w/o validation in django + bootstrap4

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, modelform

Hi i am using django + bootstrap4 to render forms. I have 'submit' and 'cancel' buttons on the forms. i am using ModelForm with Validators assigned to most of the form attributes.

### template file

```
<form action="{% url 'actor-create' %}" method="post" class="w-25 mx-auto">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form layout="horizontal" %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
</form>
```

in the view

```
def actor_create(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
     ..... rest of the code
```

When cancel button is pressed validation of the form attributes prevents the form from submitting. so view functionality never gets executed.

I want to know how to avoid validation when form is cancelled?

Following Q&A has a JavaScript based solution, I preferably don't want to write such code for every form in my website.
[How to cancel form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041009/how-to-cancel-form-submission)

Comment: Just make the cancel button a link?

Comment: Yes, that works! But is that the standard practice?

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by [Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) making it a 'a' worked for me!

```
<a href="{% url 'callmodel:index' %}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cancel</a>
```